# apache 403 error when posting more than 8186 bytes

Tags: apache, redhat

I have some strange server behaviour to trouble shoot.  The error is manifested as:

```
curl -d "post=`printf '%0.s0' {1..8186}`" -X POST https://<server-name>/index.php/start/post_test
2023-04-02 09:34:51 Length of post is : 8186%

curl -d "post=`printf '%0.s0' {1..8187}`" -X POST https://<server-name>/index.php/start/post_test
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

any POSTs smaller than 8187 characters are fine.  the php Code is:

```
public function post_test(): void
  {
    $post = $this->input->post('post');
    echo (new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Hobart')))->format(CKD_DATETIME_MYSQL) . ' Length of post is : ' . strlen($post);
  }
```

server details:

```
$uname -a
Linux mrffpa5e1d0 4.18.0-425.13.1.el8_7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Feb 2 13:01:45 EST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built:   Jan 31 2023 12:55:09

$ php -v
PHP 7.4.30 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 08:38:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

$php -i | grep post
post_max_size => 128M => 128M

$ php -i | grep max_input_vars
max_input_vars => 5000 => 5000

$sudo grep -ir security_module /etc/httpd
(no output)
$httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c

$free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1780         697         318           0         765         924
Swap:             0           0           0

$ getsebool -a | grep post
postfix_local_write_mail_spool --> on
postgresql_can_rsync --> off
postgresql_selinux_transmit_client_label --> off
postgresql_selinux_unconfined_dbadm --> on
postgresql_selinux_users_ddl --> on
selinuxuser_postgresql_connect_enabled --> off

$ getsebool -a | grep httpd
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off
httpd_dbus_sssd --> off
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_graceful_shutdown --> off
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_ipa --> off
httpd_run_preupgrade --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_serve_cobbler_files --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> off
httpd_unified --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_opencryptoki --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_use_sasl --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
```

my guess is there is a setting on a firewall machine that is causing this behaviour. i have root access to this machine, but have no information on the network architecture.

does anyone have ideas how to remove this restriction to allow larger posts to occur?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an Amazon Web Service Web Application Firewall.
which was configured with the base settings to have an 8KB maximum body size.

see: https://securityboulevard.com/2022/10/8-kb-is-not-enough-why-wafs-cant-protect-apis/ for more information.

after this restriction was removed, the posting worked with large files as expected.

```
$ post=`perl -e 'print "0" x 30000000'` ; echo "post=$post" > post.txt
$ curl -d @post.txt https://<server-name>/index.php/start/post_test

2023-04-04 09:57:13 Length of post is : 30000000
```